Error loop when using Airflow's docker compose file
I am trying to run a docker compose file from official Airflow repository (with airflow image = apache/airflow:slim-latest):
However when I run docker compose up I get the following error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

I tried to fix the issue by creating my own Dockerfile
FROM apache/airflow:slim-latest
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install libpq-dev build-essential -y
USER 50000
RUN pip install psycopg2
CMD []

And using it instead of the airflow image, but then my docker compose loops in failure :
ERROR - Failed to load CLI commands from executor: CeleryExecutor
...
ERROR - Ensure all dependencies are met and try again. If using a Celery based executor install a 3.3.0+ version of the Celery provider. If using a Kubernetes executor, install a 7.4.0+ version of the CNCF provider
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.celery'

What am I doing wrong here ? How can I make it work ?
Note :

I tried multiple airflow images, they all gave the same result


Finally found it. Using apache/airflow:2.10.0 instead of apache/airflow:slim-latest solved the issue
